# Validating radio buttons with Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

I'm creating a pay request form where the user will select how they want to be paid for overtime worked.  The two choices are 'pay' (user receives extra pay in their paycheck), or 'time' (user receives compensatory time-off to be taken at a later date).

I've created a radio button input for the user to select one or the other.  I wrote a validation to make sure one button is selected and it works fine in my test program, but when I bring it into the code for this project, the code doesn't run.  as far as I can see, there are no differences between my test program and the project.

I'm trying to use a simpler boolean and would like to stick with this option rather than a for-loop or using JQuery if possible.

here is the relevant portion of html:

```
<form class="oTcard" name="otCard" onSubmit="return submitCard()" method="post">
<div>
    <label>
        <span>request</span>
            <div style="display:block">
                <input class="radio" type="radio" id="timePay" name="timePay" value="0" ><span>time</span>
                <input class="radio" type="radio" id="timePay" name="timePay" value="1"><span>pay</span>
            </div>
     </label>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

here is the relevant portion of the javascript:

```
function submitCard (form) {
    errorString = "";
    if((form.timePay[0].checked == false) && (form.timePay[1].checked == false)) {
        alert("please choose either time or pay");
        timePay[0].focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(errorString = "") {
        form.submit()
    }
}
```

Edit to add the following:

Cyril DD's answer pointed me in the right direction.
I changed the ID's of the radio buttons to be unique to each button.
The HTML now reads:

```
<form class="oTcard" name="otCard" onSubmit="return submitCard()" method="post">
<div>
    <label>
        <span>request</span>
            <div>
                <input class="radio" type="radio" id="selectTime" name="timePay" value="0"><span>time</span>
                <input class="radio" type="radio" id="selectPay" name="timePay" value="1"><span>pay</span>
            </div>
     </label>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I then defined each button as a separate variable rather than collectively as "timePay" as I had before and changed the javascript as follows:

```
if((selectTime.checked == false) && (selectPay.checked == false)) {
    alert("please choose either time or pay");
    selectTime.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "there are no differences between my test program and the project" Did you check that your javascript isn't breaking somewhere else ? Did you check you didn't use the same function name twice ?

Comment: The validation code that i already have (validates that no text fields are blank) works properly whenever I click the submit button as-is.  it's only when I add in the validation code for the radio buttons that it stops running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your HTML : You should use the same "name" attribute, but a different ID ([demo](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio))

Some browser may not be compatible with what you're trying to do. Instead of using a "form" parameter in `function submitCard (form)`, you should just have a function `function submitCard()` and then find the elements you want in the webpage using their ID

```
function submitCard () {
    checkbox1 = document.getElementById("timeCheckBox").checked
    checkbox2 = document.getElementById("payCheckBox").checked
    if(!checkbox1 && !checkbox2)
        alert("nothing checked !");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true
    }
}
```

The HTML would look like

```
<form class="oTcard" name="otCard" onSubmit="return submitCard()" method="post">
<div>
    <label>
        <span>request</span>
            <div style="display:block">
                <input class="radio" type="radio" id="timeCheckBox" name="timePay" value="0" ><span>time</span>
                <input class="radio" type="radio" id="payCheckBox" name="timePay" value="1"><span>pay</span>
            </div>
     </label>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  See edits to original question for the final product.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a reference of the form to the `submitCard()` function.

Change

`<form class="oTcard" name="otCard" onSubmit="return submitCard()" method="post">`

to

`<form class="oTcard" name="otCard" onSubmit="return submitCard(this)" method="post">`

A couple other notes:

1. You should not use the id `timePay` more than once on the form.
2. You should not put `div` tags inside `span` tags.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x2orkh9a/)

Comment: i was under the impression that the ID (ie. timePay) had to be the same for a category of radio buttons if you wanted them to work properly.  Does only the name have to be the same then?  Should the first button be id="time" and the second be id="pay" or do you recommend a different ID-ing method?

Comment: Yes only the `name` has to be the same for radio buttons in the same group. In your specific case you don't even need an `id` on the radio buttons as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x2orkh9a/2/), but "time" and "pay" seem to make sense if you do want IDs.

Comment: It's still not working.  I changed "return submitCard()" to "return submitCard(this)" and the code still won't run. The rest of the validation runs properly, but when I add in the radio button validation at the beginning, none of it runs.

Comment: Do you agree that it's working in the example I posted? If so what is different in your code? Any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="oTcard" name="otCard" onSubmit="return submitCard(this)" method="post">
```

Have to pass argument to the function.Thats why JS validation getting failed.